# Unity interception mechanism does not work between methods inside same class

Tags: c#, .net, methods, unity-container, intercept

I´m working with C# + Unity (2.1). Intercepting methods works fine if a call comes from outside, but between methods inside the same class only the first method is intercepted.
For example:

```
    [InterceptorAttribute]
    public int A(int a, int b)
    {
         return B(a, b);
    }

    [InterceptorAttribute]
    public int B(int a, int b)
    {
         return a+b;
    }
```

The call to method B() is not intercepted.
Can anyone help?

Comment: This article should explain why that's the case: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660861(v=pandp.20).aspx.  From a quick read through that, it seems like you'd need to switch to a virtual method interceptor.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at how interception is implemented, it becomes clear as to why this happens. An interceptor is basically a proxy that wraps around the original object and forwards calls to it, in addition to calling any associated handlers:

```
public int A(int a, int b)
{
  callHandlers();
  return originalObject.A(a, b);
}

public int B(int a, int b)
{
  callHandlers();
  return originalObject.B(a, b);
}
```

Even though the two calls are individually intercepted, once `originalMethod.A` is invoked, the call to `B` will only invoke `originalObject.B`, not `proxy.B`.

Perhaps if you explain what you're using interception for, there may be a better solution to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I´m trying to clean several classes, extracting the exception-handling related code, very similar and repetitive; and also add extra info in the stacktrace (like method params values). But if a few methods calls others to complete his job, I´m in trouble. For now, I´m playing with small examples (like classic Calculator I used before) to figure out how to overcome this issue. Thanks for your answers, very useful.